# What is the probability that X=Y<Z

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $f(x,y,z)=e^{-x-y-z},\,x>0,y>0,z>0$ and 0 elsewhere, be the joint PDF of (X,Y,Z). Compute, $P(X=Y<Z).$
I started the answer as follows.

$\begin{align*}
P(X=Y<Z)=\int_{z=0}^\infty\int_{y=0}^z\int_{x=y}^z e^{-x-y-z}dxdydz.\end{align*}$

I got 1/6. But the right answer is zero. Can anyone help me to find the limits of integration?

Comment: For y the Limits are x and x because x=y

Comment: The answer is zero as $P(X=Y)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make any integrations. $X$ and $Y$ are continuous variables, therefore the probability that they are equal is $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you.

Comment: If this helped, please upvote/confirm my answer.